# MySQL query optimization related to unified ID

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables. In one table I add events, ID are auto-increment. The second table contains personal events.

So if I create event, it adds to both tables.

Here down below is a example of my code. So first of all I add a new event to general table. Then I want to add the same event to schedule table, but I need to get the ID of just added event. So I execute that second query.

Is there any optimized way how to do this or at least get the ID of just added event without extra query?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO events (title, description, user) VALUES ('$title', '$description', '".$user['id']."')");

$id = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE user='".$user['id']."' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 1"));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO schedule (uid, event) VALUES ('".$user['id']."', '".$id['id']."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: your way is not unoptimized, it's just wrong.

Comment: also, calling such function trains as `mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(` as an ugly style. make yourself `a function`  to get single value out of the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) is what you are after, I think...

You could also use the MySQL native [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in your second `INSERT` query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO schedule (uid, event) VALUES ('".$user['id']."', LAST_INSERT_ID())") or die(mysql_error());
```

...and skip retrieving the ID in PHP altogether.

Answer (score 0):

there is no "optimized" way.
there is the *right* way of getting inserted id, called `mysql_insert_id()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for the last inserted id: `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score 0):

the native php function mysql_insert_id() will do it for sure

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

consider wrapping in a transaction?  under high concurrency you could end up with the wrong id using this